# how to replace the root with object value in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Document 1:

```
{
  "data": {
    "id": "123456",
    "name": "abc",
    "value": 1
  }
}
```

**Expected Output-**

```
{
  "abc": {
    "id": "123456",
    "name": "abc",
    "value": 1
  }
}
```

Explanation: How we can replace the root with the `" name"` value, check the expected output, whatever value of the `"name"`, it becomes on the root level. and I have multiple documents.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mongo doesn't allow field names to start with a `$` meaning you can't define a dynamic key name.

You'll have to work around this restriction by playing with the data structure, here is an example of how to achieve this with [$arrayToObject](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": {
        "$arrayToObject": [
          [
            {
              k: "$data.name",
              v: "$data"
            }
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/wK0hKVrwmIK)

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this via `$project` aggregation. It should be something like this:

```
{ $project: { "$data.name": "$data" } }
```